# JS (Three.js) program only renders when event listeners are triggered

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the three.js library for JS within an HTML document, attempting to basically make a solar system (type of board-game).

Things were going smoothly until I observed that the 3d rendering was lagging a bit and thought it was a 'performance' (within my program) or a 'computer capabilities' issue. This was until I realized that if I kept my mouse moving at all times it was all rendered beautifully.

I have a couple of event functions (using them to see where the mouse points) that include a mouse_Moving_Event and a mouse_Clicking_Event which have the render function within them.

However, I also have the render function being called outside of these at the very end, like I have done in previous projects.

(here is the basic layout of my code).

```
function init() {
  *basic set up of all my camera, renderer, scene, objects,
   and event listeners, raycaster* 
}
```

(here is ONE of the event listener functions for brevity)

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // setting up the mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;         

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );                                       
    //update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects ); 
    //calculating objects intersecting the picking ray

    // sets up logic for how the rollOverMesh will be copied to the 
    // position of the intersecting rayCaster
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];
        rollOverMesh.position.copy( intersect.object.position );
        //( intersect.point );      
    }
    render();

}
```

...and finally the render function

```
function render() {
    star.rotation.y += 0.001;
    PivotObj1.rotation.y += 0.005;
    PivotObj2.rotation.y += 0.002;

    if (colonies.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < colonies.length; i++)
            colonies[i].rotation.y += 0.05
    }       

    planet1.rotation.y += 0.02; 
    planet2.rotation.y += 0.002;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

at the end I call both

```
init();
render();
```

Can anyone give me an idea of what is going on here? My render function seems to be working fine within the events, just not outside. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a render loop? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Why are you rendering on mouse move and not using requestAnimationFrame using recursion?

Comment: Oh my goodness. Yes, this was it and understood immediately. I had been basing my code off of an example I found online, where is was more like a static game board and it only needed to render when the player actually clicked. I am pretty new to graphic stuff, and have been trying to figure out exactly how the render function works - thanks!